# how to get Image src using next() in dynamic ul

Tags: jquery

I want to get image src attribute using next(). My ul in which i have this image is dynamic so I am passing my ul id to my function. following is my code which is returning me undefined valued.

```
var nxtimg=$("#"+slideid+" li#2 img").next().attr("src");
```

above line works well if I remove .attr("src"). also #2 is my li id from which I want next element but this becomes hard coded so i want to make it dynamic like,

```
var nxtimg=$("#"+slideid+" li"+liid).next().attr("src");
```

but when I add liid then it doesn't work.

Comment: Post your HTML showing the structure please. Difficult to ascertain what is happening with the failing`.next()` without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like you just need this:

```
$('#2').next().find('img').attr("src");
```

Note that a number id is only valid in HTML5 doc. not in HTML4-